# Keras 2DConvolution produces unlogical output tensor - 32x32 image becomes 32xN feature maps, instead of 32x32xN

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning, keras, convolution

According to my understanding, a 2D-Convolution applies N filters to an input image, producing N new "images" (=feature maps).

If we neglect stride/subsampling, a 32x32 image becomes a Nx32x32 tensor after 2D-Convolution with N channels:

[image: Convolution]
However, in Keras, a 32x32 input produces a 32xN output. So, my question is, how is the dimensional reduction applied? Is there another hidden layer involved in this step?

And if so, isn't the network losing its ability to view the image as it is - namely a 2D-entity?

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

This code can reproduce my above claims:

```
inputs = Input(shape=(1, 32, 32,))
shared = Convolution2D(nb_filter=10, nb_row=8, nb_col=8, subsample=(1, 1), border_mode='same', activation='relu')(inputs)
print("1 => ", inputs.shape)
print("2 => ", shared.shape)
```

It produces - as we apply 10 filters (==N) to a 32x32 grayscale image

> 1 =>  (?, 1, 32, 32)
>
> 2 =>  (?, 1, 32, 10)

Where ? is the unspecified batch size and 1 is the amount of input-channels (would be 3 for RGB, is 1 for Grayscale).

The input has a shape of 32x32, as expected.
But then, the output of the convolution has 32xN dimensions instead of 32x32xN

Comment: I cannot reproduce your outputs with the Theano backend. model.summary() is probably more appropriate to see the whole network input/output shapes.

Comment: Also, if you are using the TF backend (as you tagged it), then the input shapes are wrong, it should be (32, 32, 1).

Comment: I am using the tensorflow backend, but feeded in theano-order, so that was the problem :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be because of input format order.

From Keras docs Conv2D takes this param

> **data_format**: A string, one of channels_last (default) or
>   channels_first. The ordering of the dimensions in the inputs.
>   channels_last corresponds to inputs with shape  (batch, height, width,
>   channels) while channels_first corresponds to inputs with shape 
>   (batch, channels, height, width). It defaults to the image_data_format
>   value found in your Keras config file at ~/.keras/keras.json. If you
>   never set it, then it will be "channels_last".

So your (1, 32, 32) is actually a 1x32 image with 32 channels. Switch to (32, 32, 1) or set the data_format argument to `channels_first`.

More info on changing the default behavior: https://keras.io/backend/
You can use `keras.backend.image_data_format()` to get your setting and `set_image_data_format(data_format)` to set either `channels_first` or `channels_last`.

There is this setting because Theano and TF handle dimension ordering differently and it depends on the backed you're using.

Comment: Thanks for the writeup, but this is still the same thing: It should be (10, 32, 32) for 10 channels nevertheless. Regardless of the order, I expect 32x32x10 outputs

Comment: Actually, no. Applying a convolution to a 1x32x32(WxHxC) with stride=(1, 1), and padding=SAME should produce 1x32x10(WxHxC). The stride=(1, 1) and padding=SAME will not change the size of the image (WxH) but will produce **num_filters** channels.

Answer (score 2):

No, you are doing something wrong. The following code:

```
 import keras
 from keras.layers import Input, Convolution2D
 from keras.models import Model
 inputs = Input(shape=(1, 32, 32,))
 shared = Convolution2D(nb_filter=10, nb_row=8, nb_col=8,
 subsample=(1, 1), border_mode='same', activation='relu')(inputs)

 model = Model(inputs, shared)

 model.summary()
```

Prints the following:

```
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                       Output Shape        Param #     Connected to                     
====================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)               (None, 1, 32, 32)   0                                            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
convolution2d_1 (Convolution2D)    (None, 10, 32, 32)  650         input_1[0][0]                    
====================================================================================================
Total params: 650
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

And you can see that the output shape of Convolution2D indeed has 10 channels. If you area getting different results, check that the image_ordering is correct (and makes sense).

Comment: Thanks, the problem was indeed that I had to add dim_ordering='th' , which might have been the default for you regarding your keras config file.

As you both gave the right answer, I chose to accept the first one (not yours), hope thats ok.